# method handling in Spring MVC - same url path

Tags: url, spring-mvc, path

Im using spring MVC.
I have a list of persons with the following url:

http://localhost/PersonsWebApp/persons/list

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String allPersons(Model model){
....
}
```

Now i would like to add the view a particular person with a url like:

http://localhost/PersonsWebApp/persons/george

if i try to use the url:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/{firstname}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPersonInfo(@PathVariable("fname") String firstname)
    ....
```

there will be conflict, since there are two *GET* urls with the same path, right? How to overcome this problem without change the url's ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something different. For example [github](https://github.com/) uses these urls:

- https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-modules/pulls
- https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-modules/pull/6

Isn't that nice?

So you can try such mapping:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/persons", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String allPersons(Model model) {
    ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/person/{firstname}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPersonInfo(@PathVariable("fname") String firstname) {
    ...
    }
}
```

You don't have to put @RequestMapping on your @Controller (though you may).

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by Grzegorz is valid and you should consider it. However, for the sake of answering your question, the code sample you provided should work fine since a more specific match (with fewer patterns) is preferred over a less specific one.

Hence if the incoming URL is /persons/list, the allPersons() method should be the one invoked.